# Display KMZ file on ArcGIS Server + Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, kml, arcgis-server, kmz

I am trying to put a kmz file from my server in a google-maps-map using ArcGIS Server Google Maps API. It works fine with KML but KMZ does not show up. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Well, again I found it myself. :-)

Included the "xmlLoaded" function.

geoXml = new GGeoXml('http://myserver/kml/myKmz.kmz', xmlLoaded);
 map.addOverlay(geoXml);

Deleting it saved my day...I used it because in a tutorial it showed up and worked. 
Perhaps it has something to do with the new Javascript Version, who knows.

best
Jens